# How to add an element to an array based an index position

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document:

```
{
 "_id" : 5,
 "quizzes" : [
   { "x": 111, "score" : 10, "index" : 2 },
   { "x": 2, "score" : 8, "index" : 1 },
   { "x": 13, "score" : 5, "index" : 0 },
   { "x": 4, "score" : 6, "index" : 3 }
  ]
}
```

Now on the UI side I have the ability to add new quizzes which could be added anywhere in the list (start, end or any index above).

I can also remove a quiz which means the list index above changes. Also I can reorder a quiz which means indexes above change for those quizzes after the reordered quiz.

Now, in the mongo world how is the best way to handle these scenarios?

Should i just read the whole document and replace the whole of the quizzes sections (note my actual document will have a lot more data in the arrays)?
Or do I depending on the action I am doing (add, remove, reorder) apply a specific action ($push, etc) to be more specific on my what I am doing?

Comment: Is there any unique field value present inside `quizzes` array? i.e. value of `x` is unique across the objects inside array. If yes, then you can do it through query.

Comment: No  thinking about it, x is not unique.

Comment: Some unique field value will be helpful for the query, that you want to use.

Comment: Okay, lets say I have a unique field - if I did a reorder where x:2 is now at index 0, I would need to update all the other indexes (x:13 is now at index:1). How would I do that?

Comment: The best practice is to resave all your array reindexed because in BSON the array order is preserved